# Issue with Android List view background

Tags: android, listview

On Android, I have a problem in list view, the background turns black on selection, am not using any background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below property in your xml file in Listview Tag.

```
 android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```